# Use cmd + enter to commit and sync(push to remote) in vscode？

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In vscode, I can use cmd+enter to commit on git project
[image]

after commit, I want to use the same keyboardshortcut (cmd+enter) to sync
[image]

there is a git.sync shortcut,

```
  //   {
  // "key": "cmd+enter",
  // "command": "git.sync",
  // "when": "
  //   },
```

but It conflict with commit shortcut,
[image]

so maybe I need add a proper when clause, or achive this goal by some other way

Use cmd + enter to commit and sync(push to remote)

Comment: @rioV8 last question is how to add a proper clause, this question is ask the solution

Comment: @rioV8 these are 2 difference questions.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
{
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": ["git.commit", "git.sync"]
    }
}
```

It will both commit and push when pressing `cmd+enter`.